# Incrementar função em outra função jQuery

Tags: jquery

O código abaixo auxilia o usuário a encontrar termos e destacá-los(hightlights) dentro de qualquer elemento HTML, é funcional mas o código não destaca palavras quando digitadas sem acentuação, se destacar as palavras acentuadas mesmo digitadas sem acento o recurso teria uma utilidade ainda melhor.

**O código jQuery que busca e destaca em amarelo as palavras:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.fn.highlight = function(pat) {
        function innerHighlight(node, pat) {
            var skip = 0;
            if (node.nodeType == 3) {
                var pos = node.data.toUpperCase().indexOf(pat);
                if (pos >= 0) {
                    var spannode = document.createElement('span');
                    spannode.className = 'highlight';
                    var middlebit = node.splitText(pos);
                    var endbit = middlebit.splitText(pat.length);
                    var middleclone = middlebit.cloneNode(true);
                    spannode.appendChild(middleclone);
                    middlebit.parentNode.replaceChild(spannode, middlebit);
                    skip = 1;
                }
            } else if (node.nodeType == 1 && node.childNodes && !/(script|style) /i.test(node.tagName)) {
                for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; ++i) {
                    i += innerHighlight(node.childNodes[i], pat);
                }
            }
            return skip;
        }
        return this.each(function() {
            innerHighlight(this, pat.toUpperCase());
        });
    };
    jQuery.fn.removeHighlight = function() {
        function newNormalize(node) {
            for (var i = 0, children = node.childNodes, nodeCount = children.length; i < nodeCount; i++) {
                var child = children[i];
                if (child.nodeType == 1) {
                    newNormalize(child);
                    continue;
                }
                if (child.nodeType != 3) { continue; }
                var next = child.nextSibling;
                if (next == null || next.nodeType != 3) { continue; }
                var combined_text = child.nodeValue + next.nodeValue;
                new_node = node.ownerDocument.createTextNode(combined_text);
                node.insertBefore(new_node, child);
                node.removeChild(child);
                node.removeChild(next);
                i--;
                nodeCount--;
            }
        }
        return this.find("span.highlight").each(function() {
            var thisParent = this.parentNode;
            thisParent.replaceChild(this.firstChild, this);
            newNormalize(thisParent);
        }).end();
    };
    $(function() {
        $('#text-search').bind('keyup change', function(ev) {
            var searchTerm = $(this).val();
            $('.categorias').removeHighlight();
            if ( searchTerm ) {
                 $('.categorias').highlight( searchTerm );
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Aqui o input que recebe a entrada do termo para destacar:**

```
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group addon addon-destaca-termos">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></span>
        <input placeholder="Destaque termos da lista" type="text" class="input-destaca-termos form-control input-sm" id="text-search">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Elemento que foi referenciado no handler de #text-search:**

```
<div class='categorias'>
    <ul>
        <li>xyz abc wotf</li>
        <li>xyz abc wotf</li>
        <li>xyz abc wotf</li>
        <li>xyz abc wotf</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**A função tira acentos que tenho mas não sei integrar:**

```
<script>
    function tiraAcentos(i){
      var i = i.toLowerCase().trim();
      var acentos = "ãáàâäéèêëíìîïõóòôöúùûüç";
      var sem_acentos = "aaaaaeeeeiiiiooooouuuuc";
      for(var x=0; x<i.length; x++){
         var str_pos = acentos.indexOf(i.substr(x,1));
         if(str_pos != -1){
            i = i.replace(acentos.charAt(str_pos),sem_acentos.charAt(str_pos));
         }
      }
      return i;
    }
</script>
```

```js
jQuery.fn.highlight = function(pat) {
        function innerHighlight(node, pat) {
            var skip = 0;
            if (node.nodeType == 3) {
                var pos = node.data.toUpperCase().indexOf(pat);
                if (pos >= 0) {
                    var spannode = document.createElement('span');
                    spannode.className = 'highlight';
                    var middlebit = node.splitText(pos);
                    var endbit = middlebit.splitText(pat.length);
                    var middleclone = middlebit.cloneNode(true);
                    spannode.appendChild(middleclone);
                    middlebit.parentNode.replaceChild(spannode, middlebit);
                    skip = 1;
                }
            } else if (node.nodeType == 1 && node.childNodes && !/(script|style) /i.test(node.tagName)) {
                for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; ++i) {
                    i += innerHighlight(node.childNodes[i], pat);
                }
            }
            return skip;
        }
        return this.each(function() {
            innerHighlight(this, pat.toUpperCase());
        });
    };
    jQuery.fn.removeHighlight = function() {
        function newNormalize(node) {
            for (var i = 0, children = node.childNodes, nodeCount = children.length; i < nodeCount; i++) {
                var child = children[i];
                if (child.nodeType == 1) {
                    newNormalize(child);
                    continue;
                }
                if (child.nodeType != 3) { continue; }
                var next = child.nextSibling;
                if (next == null || next.nodeType != 3) { continue; }
                var combined_text = child.nodeValue + next.nodeValue;
                new_node = node.ownerDocument.createTextNode(combined_text);
                node.insertBefore(new_node, child);
                node.removeChild(child);
                node.removeChild(next);
                i--;
                nodeCount--;
            }
        }
        return this.find("span.highlight").each(function() {
            var thisParent = this.parentNode;
            thisParent.replaceChild(this.firstChild, this);
            newNormalize(thisParent);
        }).end();
    };
    $(function() {
        $('#text-search').bind('keyup change', function(ev) {
            var searchTerm = $(this).val();
            $('.categorias').removeHighlight();
            if ( searchTerm ) {
                 $('.categorias').highlight( searchTerm );
            }
        });
    });
```

```css
.categorias .highlight {
 background-color: #fff34d;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
 box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
.categorias .highlight {
  padding:1px 4px;
  margin:0 -4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group addon addon-destaca-termos">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></span>
        <input placeholder="Destaque termos da lista" type="text" class="input-destaca-termos form-control input-sm" id="text-search">
    </div>
</div>
<div class='categorias'>
    <ul>
        <li>xyz abc wotf</li>
        <li>xyz abc wotf</li>
        <li>xyz abc wotf</li>
        <li>xyz abc wotf</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Podes criar um [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) para ser mais fácil ajudar?

Comment: @iamdlm feito, confere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Eliseu só precisa de uma simples alteração na função `jQuery.fn.highlight`

Está assim:

```
var pos = node.data.toUpperCase().indexOf(pat);
```

Altera pra ficar assim:

```
var pos = tiraAcentos(node.data).indexOf(tiraAcentos(pat));
```

Answer (score 2):

Talvez a [String.prototype.normalize()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) resolva o problema, funciona assim:

```js
var string = "Ça été Mičić. ÀÉÏÓÛ";
console.log(string);

var string_norm = string.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "");
console.log(string_norm);
```

Tem a vantagem de que não precisa manter uma função (tiraAcentos) para tratar disso.

Comment: Obrigado pela sua sapiência, vou memorizar essa resposta, mas a função já uso para outras finalidades então pensei em reutilizá-la nisso.

Comment: Claro, fica com essa referência para o futuro.